# How to pick a sequence of numbers (from a fixed list) that will sum to a target number?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let say I've a target number and a list of possibile values that I can pick to create a sequence that, once summed every picked number, will sum to the target:

```
target = 31
list = 2, 3, 4
possible sequence: 3 2 4 2 2 2 4 2 3 2 3 2
```

I'd like to:

1. first decide if there is any sequence that will reach the target
2. return one of the many (possible) sequence

This is my [attempt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/228f3a45fe326b4e):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

inline int GetRandomInt(int min = 0, int max = 1) {
    uint64_t timeSeed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::seed_seq ss{ uint32_t(timeSeed & 0xffffffff), uint32_t(timeSeed >> 32) };
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
    rng.seed(ss);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> unif(min, max);

    return unif(rng);
}

void CreateSequence(int target, std::vector<int> &availableNumbers) {
    int numAttempts = 1;
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<int> elements;

    while (count != target) {
        while (count < target) {
            int elem = availableNumbers[GetRandomInt(0, availableNumbers.size() - 1)];

            count += elem;
            elements.push_back(elem);
        }

        if (count != target) {
            numAttempts++;
            count = 0;
            elements.clear();
        }
    }

    int size = elements.size();
    std::cout << "count: " << count << " | " << "num elements: " << size << " | " << "num attempts: " << numAttempts << std::endl;
    for (auto it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it  << " ";
    }   
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> availableNumbers = { 2, 3, 4 };

    CreateSequence(31, availableNumbers);
}
```

But it can loop infinitely if the list of number can't be appropriate to reach such sum; example:

```
std::vector<int> availableNumbers = { 3 };

CreateSequence(8, availableNumbers);
```

No sequence of 3 will sum to 8. Also, if the list is huge and the target number high, it can lead to a huge amount of processing (cause lots of while check fails).

How would you implement this kind of algorithm?

Comment: I'm thinking `backtracking` paradigm might be useful here: if the current sum exceeds the target you can disregard that branch and move on to another permutation.

Comment: Isn't it a [change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested code is possibly very fast, since it is heuristic. But as you said, it gets potentially trapped in a nearly endless loop.

If you want to avoid this situation, you have to search the complete set of possible combinations.

### Abstraction

Let's define our algorithm as a function `f` with a scalar target `t` and a vector `<b>` as parameters returning a vector of coefficients `<c>`, where `<b>` and `<c>` have the same dimension:
`<c> = f(t, <b>)`

First the given set of numbers `Sg` should be reduced to their reduced set `Sr` so we reduce the dimension of our solution vector `<c>`. E.g. `{2,3,4,11}` can be reduced to `{2,3}`. We get this by calling our algorithm recursively by splitting `Sg` into a new target `ti` with the remaining numbers as the new given set `Sgi` and ask the algorithm, if it finds any solution (a non-zero vector). If so, remove that target `ti` from the original given set `Sg`. Repeat this recursively until no solutions found any more.

Now we can understand this set of numbers as a polynomial, where we are looking for possible coefficients `ci` to get our target `t`. Let's call each element in `Sb` `bi` with `i={1..n}`.

Our test sum `ts` is the sum over all `i` for `ci * bi`, where each `ci` can run from `0` to `ni = floor(t/bi)`.

The number of possible tests `N` is now the product over all `ni+1`: `N = (n1+1) * (n2+1) * ... * (ni+1)`.

Iterate now over all possibilities by representing the coefficient vector `<c>` as an vector of integers and incrementing `c1` and carrying over an overrun to the next element in the vector, resetting c1 and so forth.

### Example

```
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int evaluatePolynomial(const vector<int> &base, const vector<int> &coefficients)
{
    int v=0;
    for(unsigned long i=0; i<base.size(); i++){
        v += base[i]*coefficients[i];
    }
    return v;
}

static bool isZeroVector(vector<int> &v)
{
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
        if(*it != 0){
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}

static vector<int> searchCoeffs(int target, vector<int> &set) {
    // TODO: reduce given set

    vector<int> n = set;
    vector<int> c = vector<int>(set.size(), 0);

    for(unsigned long int i=0; i<set.size(); i++){
        n[i] = target/set[i];
    }

    c[0] = 1;

    bool overflow = false;
    while(!overflow){
        if(evaluatePolynomial(set, c) == target){
            return c;
        }

        // increment coefficient vector
        overflow = true;
        for(unsigned long int i=0; i<c.size(); i++){
            c[i]++;
            if(c[i] > n[i]){
                c[i] = 0;
            }else{
                overflow = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return vector<int>(set.size(), 0);
}

static void print(int target, vector<int> &set, vector<int> &c)
{
    for(unsigned long i=0; i<set.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<c[i]; j++){
            cout << set[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << target << " = ";
    for(unsigned long i=0; i<set.size(); i++){
        cout << " +" << set[i] << "*" << c[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> set = {4,3,2};
    int target = 31;

    auto c = searchCoeffs(target, set);
    print(target, set,c);
}
```

That code prints

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 
31 =  +4*7 +3*1 +2*0
```

### Further Thoughts

- productive code should test for zeros in any given values
- the search could be improved by incrementing the next coefficient if the evaluated polynomial already exceeded the target value.
- further speedup is possible, when calculating the difference of the target value and the evaluated polynomial when c1 is set to zero, and checking if that difference is a multiple of b1. If not, c2 could be incremented straight forward.
- Perhaps there exist some shortcuts exploiting the least common multiple

Comment: Nice, but this doesn't return a list of possible sequence I'll use. For example: if I set `vector<int> set = {2, 3, 4};` with target 12, it returns `2 2 2 2 2 2`. What if I'd like to place `2 3 2 3 2`? I should combine it with 6 and found 2*3? Its a pain to manage.

Comment: Or are you suggesting to use your approch to see if the set can be used, and THAN my approch?

Comment: You are right, it only prints that sequence. But generating that sequence in a vector or list should be easy. I'm a bit confused, why a systematic sequence (not shuffeld in any way) is not aceptable. You said, you want to get any of the multiple solutions.

Comment: The given algorithm could easily return a list of all solutions, and then you could randomly select one of them.

Answer (score 0):

As ihavenoidea proposed, I would also try backtracking. In addition, I will sort the numbers in decreasing order, il order to speed up the process.

Note: a comment would be more appropriate than an answer, but I am not allowed to. Hope it helps. I will suppress this answer if requested.